# Make my app silently login to default predefined google drive account instead of asking users account

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

thanks for reading!

So I recently got some good ideas but my knowledge just isn't enough here. Even though my google-ing should be top notch I could't find anything about this.

**I want the user to take a picture of something, upload the image to google drive, and download it as .txt file, so I would like to do an OCR. Making all the users give me their google drive access is not what I want. I want to have one dedicated google drive, where they automatically log into when the app starts, upload and download the stuff from that one same google drive account for everyone. The problem is that I can't really figure out how to do that. I'm quite new to API-s as well.**

Comment: It sounds like you want an OCR system, not Google Drive. Drive is not intended to be used this way, so if your app hits any level of scale you are going to run into rate limiting and bad performance.

Comment: There was a possibility to OCR an image from google drive that you've uploaded, but I guess I would run into the limit pretty quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you describe is best achieved using a Service Account. See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: Also consider using Google Cloud Storage, its designed for what you are trying to do.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/

Comment: Google Cloud, yes. Thank you!